# How do I get version of Chrome on Selenium Node?

Tags: selenium-grid

I'm learning how to run tests on SeleniumGRID.
I have problem with specifying the version of Chrome browser.
I have 1 Selenium Hub and 1 Selenium Node connected to the Hub.
Selenium Node has Chrome browser. The version of browser is:

> 85.0.4183.102

If I use:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
capability.setCapability("platform", "Linux");
```

it will work fine. But if I add:

```
capability.setCapability("version", "85.0");
```

I will get error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platform: LINUX, version: 85.0}

What should I put in version to run it?
I was trying various possibility (85, 85.0, 85.0.4183.102) but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because Node probably doesn't have specified the Chrome version.
I ran the Node with configuration in json file. Then I was able to specify the Chrome version in this json file.
And then I was able to run tests with specified chrome version.